# Loading image while script is loaded in iframe

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, iframe, loader

I have a simple form where people fill in some data. When pressed the submit button this data will be handelded in a php script, this takes some time (10 seconds). When the php script is finished it will give his result into a iframe.

Now I want a loading image on this iframe while the php script is running.
So how can I trigger the loading image when the submit button is pressed and that the image will be go away when the iframe is fully loaded.

Here is a Jsfiddle of my form:
http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=oFhTbTvn2d

Has someone a Jsfiddle example of something that looks like I want?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Showing a loading image while loading php script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11380425/showing-a-loading-image-while-loading-php-script)

Comment: your goal is to just technically show a loader (whether it's loading or not doesn't matter).  Once the data is loaded, you can just cover or empty the loading gif.

Comment: You should load the results using an AJAX request instead of an iframe. Show the image when you trigger the AJAX request, then hide it when you get a response. That is the best way to do what you're asking.